# How do I get the differential of a function that depends on the sum of itself?

Tags: functions, derivatives, summation

I have a very long and complicated formulation of an equation $X(P,T)$ and I want to calculate its differential. I will try to make it the simplest as possible. If I am missing anything, please, don't hesitate to ask me.

I managed to have it in the form :

$$dX = \frac{\partial X}{\partial P}dP + \frac{\partial X}{\partial T}dT + \frac{\partial X}{\partial k}dk$$

where I know:

$$\frac{\partial X}{\partial P} = A.X$$
$$\frac{\partial X}{\partial T} = B.X$$
$$\frac{\partial X}{\partial k} = C.X$$

with (A,B,C) are functions that I know and depends or $P,T,k$ as : $A=A(P)$, $B=B(T,k)$ and $C=C(T,k)$.

The part that is causing me troubles is the $k$ function because it is a function of $X$ :

$$k=\sum_{i=1}^N k_i X_i$$
and
$$dk = \sum_{i=1}^N k_i dX_i$$

$k_i$ are constants and $dX_i$ is the $i^{th}$ element of $dX$ from the 1st equation.

How can I get rid of the $dk$ term and get something that would look like $dX = f(P,T,X)dP + g(P,T,X)dT$ ?

**Edit:** $P$ and $T$ variables are floats while $X,k$ are 1-D matrices as well as $A,B,C$.

**Edit:** Below is the formulation of the vector X, which is computed in an iterative way:

$$X_i^{n+1} = exp\left( \frac{H_i}{T} + (1+\alpha x) \left(\frac{M_i}{1+xe^{\alpha x}} - \frac{k_i}{k} \right) \right) $$

where $H_i, M_i$ are constant matrices, $\alpha$ is a constant, $n$ is the iteration number,

$x=\frac{k}{PT}$,

$k=\sum_{j=1}^N k_j X_{j}^n$ with $k_j$ constants.

My goal is to differentiate X to obtain the form : $dX = f(P,T,X)dP + g(P,T,X)dT$.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: What are the $X_i$ here?

Comment: function $X$ is actually a vector and $X_i$ is for the $i^{th} element of $X$

Comment: You say that $X=X(P,T)$ and then start differentiating wrt $k$. That makes no sense, please edit your question.

Comment: You're right, $X$ depends of $k$ as well but as $k$ is a function of $X$, I did not wrote it in $X(P,T)$. That is the point of my question, how to get $dX$ that only depends on $dP$ and $dT$ ?